# Missing properties in Google Cloud Storage .NET library

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I am using .NET library to connect to Google Cloud Storage. I am particularly interested in a method:
ListObjects(String, String, ListObjectsOptions)

In docs here :
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/ListObjectsOptions.cs#L81

and here:
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.ListObjectsOptions.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_ListObjectsOptions_Delimiter

I can see that in ListObjectOptions there is a property "Fields" which is used to specify which properties of object I would like to list, however when I use this class in my C# program, there is no such property:

[image]

Is this property removed? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the history of that file:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/commits/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/ListObjectsOptions.cs

you can see the property “Fields” was Added on 2 Jan 2020. 
Maybe you don't have the latest version?